# when i try to pass parameters from url to views by regex in django=1.9,i got this error,i dont know why

Tags: regex, django, python-3.x

i want to pass parameters to my app.views with regex,but i got the fellow error.
my regex is `"^(?Pd+)"`,which means  to pass the passed one or more digits as parameters to the detail in the views as parameters, where `?P` defines the name used to identify the matching content.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/ENV3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/ENV3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/root/ENV3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/root/ENV3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/root/ENV3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/root/ENV3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 27, in check_resolver
    warnings.extend(check_pattern_startswith_slash(pattern))
  File "/root/ENV3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 63, in check_pattern_startswith_slash
    regex_pattern = pattern.regex.pattern
  File "/root/ENV3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 203, in regex
    (regex, six.text_type(e)))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: "^(?Pd+)/$" is not a valid regular expression: unknown extension ?Pd at position 2
```

Comment: "my regex is "^(?Pd+)",which means to pass the passed one or more digits as parameters [...]" According to who?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It seems a real problem you are encountering. But would you please first learn to format your question properly? [How to format your code properly in OS](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: i got this tutorial from [this](http://wiki.jikexueyuan.com/project/django-set-up-blog/views-url.html).

Comment: Did you scroll down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [tutorial you are using](http://wiki.jikexueyuan.com/project/django-set-up-blog/views-url.html) has an error, which is why the example is not working.

Please always refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/) and [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) (a [Chinese translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/2.0/) is also available, but for version 2.0 only).

Your error is because `?P` is used when you want to name a capture group, and the syntax is `?P<name>(pattern)`. The Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) goes into more detail on this.

In your case, you need `url(r'^(\d+)/$', 'article.views.detail', name='detail'),`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Django Official Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#named-groups), it says

> In Python regular expressions, the syntax for named regular-expression
>   groups is 
> **(?P<name>pattern)**, where **name** is the name of the group and
>   **pattern** is some pattern to match.

In your case, it should be

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       # your code
                       # your code
                       url(r'^(?P<my_args>d+)/$', 'article.views.detail', name='detail'),
                       )
```

**Example**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.special_case_2003),
    url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
    url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
    url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/(?P<day>[0-9]{2})/$', views.article_detail),
]
```

Comment: it worked with expression of `url(r'^(\d+)/$', 'article.views.detail', name='detail'),.   thanks a lot for your answer anyway